# Rails 5 ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken on Production Enviroment Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx, ruby-on-rails-5

On Rails 5.2, SSL enviroment, running as reverse_proxy with Nginx, whenever I submit a form I get the error:

> HTTP Origin header (https://agro2business.com.br) didn't match
>   request.base_url (https://agro2business.com.br, agro2business.com.br)
>
> Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
>
> ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
>   (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken)

I'd read about configuring params and Nginx for passing on headers in another StackOverflow questions but no luck so far. My nginx config file:

> proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
>           }
>
> location / {
>
> ```
>             proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
>             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
>             proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
>             proxy_redirect off;
>             proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
>             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
>             proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
>             proxy_set_header X-Real-Port $server_port;
>             proxy_set_header X-Real-Scheme $scheme;
>             proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
>             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
>             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
>     }
> ```

Why is Rails trying to compare the header with two values?

> request.base_url (https://agro2business.com.br, agro2business.com.br)

Comment: Are you using Devise?

Comment: @a3y3 Yes I'm using Devise gem

Comment: It's likely that the CSRF token is not passed in the form. Search up on how to include it in your POST requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem was that in my nginx config I was setting header *Host* two times and this was causing url generation misleadings, which in turn was invalidating form submissions.

```
  proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        **proxy_set_header Host $http_host;**
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        **proxy_set_header Host $http_host;**
        proxy_set_header X-Real-Port $server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
```

Just removing one the two ***proxy_set_header Host $http_host;*** did the trick

Comment: I did not have that issue (with host) and it's for Rails 6, but reason was something missing from the headers. When I put all you have it just works. It was pretty frustrating to figure it out :) Thanks!